# Can I include odd characters in Groovy variable names?

Tags: maven, groovy, gradle

I am migrating from Maven3 to Gradle and I have an dependency on an internal project that includes some properties as version identifiers. When I try to compile my project, it complains about the dependency not found. The problem is these properties either use a period '.' or a dash '-' (e.g., cargo.version, supported-spring-version).

Is there a way in Groovy to declare a variable with odd characters?

def 'supported-spring-version' = '3.1.0.RELEASE'

Answer (score 7):

You can't use def, but you can declare them in the current binding

```
this.'some-string' = '3'

println​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ this.'some-string'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

There's probably a better way round this though, but there's not enough information in your question to reliably suggest an alternative