# Groovy: Adding attributes and namespace to the xml

Tags: groovy

I am building Xml building with Closures like this:

```
def buildRequestXml {
 def RequestXml{  //add namespace and version attribute on root
   FirstName("Name1")
   LastName("Name2")
   DOB("12/19/1983") //add attribute format="mm/dd/yyyy"
 }
 return new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind(RequestXml)
}
```

How would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
import groovy.xml.* 

def buildRequestXml() {
   def requestXml = {  //add namespace and version attribute on root
       mkp.xmlDeclaration()
       root {
           FirstName("Name1")
           LastName("Name2")
           DOB("12/19/1983") //add attribute format="mm/dd/yyyy"
       }
   }
   new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind( requestXml )
}

println buildRequestXml()
```

Or `XmlUtil.serialize` adds it for you I believe...

Comment: Can I use `mkp` just like that without declaring it anywhere?

Comment: It's part of streamingmarkupbuilder which is the delegate of the closure when it's passed to bind

Answer (score 1):

Please see: 
[Creating XML using Groovy's MarkupBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Creating+XML+using+Groovy%27s+MarkupBuilder).  Particularly the section on "Namespace Aware Example".

Basically, you do it just like tim_yates told you above, but put the namespace/prefix bindings in by hand:

```
import groovy.xml.* 

def buildRequestXml() {
   def requestXml = {  //add namespace and version attribute on root
       mkp.xmlDeclaration()
       'test:root'('xmlns:test': 'urn:blah') {
           FirstName("Name1")
           LastName("Name2")
           DOB("12/19/1983") //add attribute format="mm/dd/yyyy"
       }
   }
   new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind( requestXml )
}

println buildRequestXml()
```

It's the special single quote syntax that allows you to put the colon in the name.  This is how you give variables names in groovy that aren't valid java syntax.  For more inforamation see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466608/can-i-include-odd-characters-in-groovy-variable-names).

Comment: You can use double quotes as well :-)